# Problems updating my SQLite db

Tags: php, sqlite

Here is my PHP code:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE rs_api_token set token=:token, expiration=:expiration, tenant=:tenant, catalog=:catalog WHERE id = 1";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql_update);
$q->execute(array(':token' => $token, ':expiration' => $expiration, ':tenant' => $tenant, ':catalog' => serialize($catalog)));
```

I am able to retrieve the information from my SQLite db, but I am unable to update the content.

I am not getting any errors and when I echo the variables like you can see in the code I get all the right values. It just does not update it. Could it be, because on of my values is too big? If that's the case why is it not telling me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to update the file permission by using this command:

```
chmod 777
```

I also had to do it for the folder that contained the db file.

Comment: `0777` might be dangerous, just make sure the user/group (`0600`/`0660`) can write to the SQLite file (and to the directory as well, if the file doesn't yet exists or you are using journaling).